# IronPython - "AttributeError: object has no attribute" with custom classes

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython, attributeerror

This seems like there is just a simple error that I cannot figure out. I am using IronPython in a C# WPF application and am getting the following error when trying to run a function from a custom C# class:`AttributeError: 'MyScriptingFunctions' object has no attribute 'Procedure'`.

The python script I'm running is very simple and has two lines. Line 1 executes fine, the error occurs on line 2.

```
    txt.Text = "some text"
    MyFunc.Procedure(5)
```

MyScriptingFunctions.cs:

```
class MyScriptingFunctions
{
    public MyScriptingFunctions() {}

    public void Procedure(int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing procedure " + num); 
    }
}
```

Here is how I setup the IronPython engine:

```
     private void btnRunScript_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        MyScriptingFunctions scriptFuncs = new MyScriptingFunctions();
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

        ScriptRuntime runtime = engine.Runtime;
        runtime.LoadAssembly(typeof(String).Assembly);
        runtime.LoadAssembly(typeof(Uri).Assembly);

        //Set Variable for the python script to use
        scope.SetVariable("txt", fullReadResultsTextBox);
        scope.SetVariable("MyFunc", scriptFuncs);
        string code = this.scriptTextBox.Text;
        try
        {
            ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
            source.Execute(scope);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionOperations eo;
            eo = engine.GetService<ExceptionOperations>();
            string error = eo.FormatException(ex);

            MessageBox.Show(error, "There was an Error");
            return;
        }

    }
```

I am simply setting two variables:`txt` which is of type `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`, and `MyFunc` which is an object of my custom class `MyScriptingFunctions`.

What am I doing wrong and why does the python script execute the TextBox methods correctly and not my custom class's methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only think I can see that might be an issue, or just a copy-paste error, is that the `MyScriptingFunctions` in not `public`. That *shouldn't* be an issue because you're passing an instance in, not trying to import the class, but it's worth a try. Otherwise everything looks fine.

Comment: Had same issue, hadn't thought to make the class public. For others stuck with this issue: your class does not need to be public, but the **method needs to be public enough to be seen outside the assembly**. For example, you can have an internal class that implements a public interface, so long as python only calls the interface methods.

Comment: I can confirm, run into this issue a minute ago. Thanks.